# unable to insert into mysql table using python

Tags: python, mysql, csv

I'm trying to insert rows in my sql table using a csv file in python.

There are five columns (id(autoincrement, primary, int),Event(int), Edition(int), Subscription(varchar), Daystogo(varchar)

My csv has 4 columns (Event, Edition, Subscription, Daystogo). I want to insert these into the table and let id be assigned in autoincremental way.

```
mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
        user='user', password='password',
                              host='host',
                              database='opm')
mycursor = mydb.cursor()


csv_data=csv.reader("mycsvfile.csv")
for row in csv_data:
    print(row)
    mycursor.execute("INSERT INTO opm (Event, Edition, Subscription, Daystogo) VALUES (%s,%s,%s,%s)", (int,int,str, str))
```

This is the error that i have been receiving

```
csv_data=csv.reader("mycsvfile.csv")
for row in csv_data:
    print(row)
    mycursor.execute("INSERT INTO opm (Event, Edition, Subscription, Daystogo) VALUES (%s,%s,%s,%s)", (int,int,str, str))


['m']
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-51-5b5e2c804099>", line 4, in <module>
    mycursor.execute("INSERT INTO opm (Event, Edition, Subscription, Daystogo) VALUES (%s,%s,%s,%s)", (int,int,str, str))

  File "E:\Data Science\pyWork\PyProjects\Program\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\cursor.py", line 547, in execute
    psub = _ParamSubstitutor(self._process_params(params))

  File "E:\Data Science\pyWork\PyProjects\Program\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\cursor.py", line 430, in _process_params
    "Failed processing format-parameters; %s" % err)

ProgrammingError: Failed processing format-parameters; Python 'type' cannot be converted to a MySQL type
```

for code

```
mycursor.execute("INSERT INTO opm (Event, Edition, Subscription, Daystogo) VALUES (%s,%s,%s,%s)")
```

the error is

```
ProgrammingError: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '%s,%s,%s,%s)' at line 1
```

Please help me out how can I insert the rows in mysql table

Comment: What are the arguments `(int,int,str, str)` supposed to do?

Comment: What are you expecting `(int,int,str, str)` to do? That should be replaced with the variables containing the values you want to insert.

Comment: to specify the data type. Im new and saw this code used somewhere. Please correct if wrong

Comment: when i remove (int,int,str, str). it says "ProgrammingError: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '%s,%s,%s,%s)' at line 1"

Comment: For future: use Stack Overflow Snippets only for executable web code (HTML+JS+CSS). Use normal code formatting (indent by four spaces, can be done by selecting code and hitting Ctrl-K, or Command-K on Mac) for any other kind of code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your CSV has four columns,

```
mycursor.execute("INSERT INTO opm (Event, Edition, Subscription, Daystogo) VALUES (%s,%s,%s,%s)", row)
```

should work (the second parameter needs to be a list or a tuple with elements to be bound to the placeholders; since you have four placeholders, you need a four-element list or tuple of data (not data *types*!).

Comment: it says ProgrammingError: Not enough parameters for the SQL statement. I even tried tuple(row). but same error

Comment: You're doing a `print(row)` beforehand; confirm it actually has four elements.